# Can I move my web app Vuejs to NativeScript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Good,
My question is really simple. I have a web project made in Vuejs and I would like to know if there is any way to take this project and to mirror it to NativeScript-Vue in some way.

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automated way to migrate your app. The templates should be completely rewritten as the mobile world has different UI components and concepts. Your scripts and styles, for the most part, should work the same way. You will need to figure out how to do the routing as the default vue.js router is not supported. You can check the [manual routing article](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/) fore more information.

Comment: Thank you anthares, I understand that I must create a specific project to do this.

A greeting!

Comment: However, there is a share code between the web and the mobile project. Check out this article: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/code-sharing-with-nativescript-vue